# Excel VBA - ComboBox search while user types

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Im not sure if this is possible, but I have a user form with a combobox that lists customers.

The current format of the values in the list are *town - customer*. When a user types into the ComboBox, they are able to search the values within the list.

However, this only works from the first character on, ie - the user MUST type in the town first followed by "-" as it appears in the list.

Is it possible to make the ComboBox search any value like the input from the user. ie - without typing the town first, the user could type the customer name only.

Comment: Yes this is possible. Please note, without any code, it is going to be really hard to help you. Please share your research.

Comment: There is no VBA attached to this ComboBox. It is used in conjunction with several TextBoxes, and ListBoxes to enter data into a sheet. This is all working as intended. I have no code, as I am not even sure where to start. Other than changing this setting, MatchEntry - 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete, I have not changed anything. The only other options for the MatchEntry setting are fmMatchEntryFirstLetter, or fmMatchEntryNone, which to my understanding won't achieve what I am after. Hence the question, is this possible, if so how?

Comment: Excel has 2 sets of controls, one being very limited, the other offering a lot of control. The funny thing is, both have their own toolbar in Excel that you need to activate in order to place them, but they both also can be used with VBA. Try the other one and see if it works for you.